# refresh page after click delete button in the table angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript

I develop my application in angular 10 and i want to reload (my page)my table when i delete one row, i use location.reload(), but there is no refresh.
This is the code

```
openDialog(contact:Contact) {
  Swal.fire({
    title: 'Voulez-vous supprimer ce contact?',
    icon: 'warning',
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonText: 'Supprimer!',
    cancelButtonText: 'Annuler'
  }).then((result) => {
    if (result.value) {
       return this.removeContactService.sendContact(contact.id).subscribe(data => {
        Swal.fire(
          'Effectué!',
          'Le contact a été supprimé.',
          'success'
        )
       this.getContactList();
       location.reload();
    },error => {
      console.log("Erreur lors de la suppression du contact : ",error);
    });
  } 
  })
}
```

How can i refresh the page containing my table when the user click delete button

Comment: You're returning `sendContact` function, so code after that won't be executed. Try to remove `return`.

Comment: Did you check that code does run into the `subscribe` callback without error?

Comment: Hello @thanhdx, i have this error in my suscribe callback :error: {error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token R in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at XMLHtt…, text: "Remove Success!"}
headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}
message: "Http failure during parsing for http://myserver/book/remove"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
url: "http://myserver/book/remove"
__proto__: HttpResponseBase

Comment: Maybe there's an error when parsing the result from HTTP response, so the subscribe go into the error callback, not the data callback, so the code was not run into `location.reload()`.

Comment: Thanks @thanhdx , this is my api calling @RequestMapping(value = "/remove", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public ResponseEntity remove(@RequestBody String id) {
  contactService.removeOne(Long.parseLong(id));

  return new ResponseEntity("Remove Success!", HttpStatus.OK);
 } I return the text Remove Success which is visible in the error object .